# Handle very large data with dictionnary of dataframes

Tags: pandas, ipython

I have a very large pandas dataframe (300 mio records) with mutiple key_id columns. Data is a multi-variate time series + text labels (string 50 char)

As I need to do analysis based on one specific key_id, I decide to create 
a dictionnary based on

```
 (key_id, sub dictionnary containing compute results).
```

sub_dictionnary is a collection of dataframe (filtered by key_id), time series list, float values.

Question is :

1. Is dictionnary of dataframe efficient vs a big dataframe,
   especially if the computed are not map-reduced but time series computation ?

Comment: It should be 1 question at a time

Comment: ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: regarding your question of efficiency, are you asking just speed of looking up and returning your df based on key_id in a dict versus having all dfs stacked in a single df where you would then need to either lookup or groupby on key_id and then call `get_group`? It seems reasonable to me use either a dict or `groupby` and then call `get_group`

Comment: There are many custom functions applied on each subset (df filtered by key_id: aggregation and lookup of float column values).